# Docker stack deploy only works on manager node

Tags: docker

I try to start a docker swarm with `docker stack deploy -c my-compose.yml --with-registry-auth anyname`. The docker Visualizer shows me, that docker try to deploy the containers on my worker nodes, but ended up always in starting state. At the end all containers run at the manager node.

The nodes are all available and active, I've checked it with `docker node ls`. All needed ports are open. The nodes are running on linux V-Server from different providers. Maybe anyone has an idea or a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem is solved. I've installed my own debian image on the V-server. I think it was a network driver problem.